# What type of verb conjugation is this 巻き込まれてしまた

Tags: conjugations

Below is an example I found from Internet.

途中で渋滞に巻き込まれてしまたのです。
(The meaning I guess : "The reason is, along the way, I was stuck in a traffic jam")

But from "巻き込まれてしまた" I could not figure out what kind of conjugation was applied to the verb 巻き込む.

Any one please help.

Comment: The example you found is likely borked (unless there was some dialect which shortened it to しまた). It should be 〜しまった.  Check 「〜て しまう」

Comment: @macraf Thank you, because there are about 50000 results when googling the "巻き込まれてしまた", I also think it may be some kind of dialect.

Comment: for てしまう you could have a look at https://namakajiri.net/nikki/chao/

Comment: @UenX I think you mean 24 results. [Try clicking on the third page.](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%B7%BB%E3%81%8D%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%22&hl=en&prmd=ivns&ei=i_LGV63kDYe3swHY5rKACg&start=20&sa=N)

Comment: @永劫回帰 Thank you! Until now I only know about two meanings of " てしまう" which are "to do something by accident" and "to finish completely"

Comment: @oals Oops...thank you..my bad. Then macraf's first assumption would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather see: *got* instead of *was* in your translation because of しまった (which is written for whatever reason without っ).

The conjugation at hand is:

> 巻き込む　＋　れる（passive)　＋　てしまう (end up)　＋　た　(past)